# SQLAlchemy pass parameters with like '%STRING%' in raw sql

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sql:

```
select *
from my table
where exists (
    select
    from unnest(procedure) elem
    where elem like '%String%'
          )
```

It works well when directly execute in database ide.

My question is how can I set 'String' as a parameters ?

I have tried:

```
String = 'hello world'

my_query = '''
    select *
    from my_table
    where exists (
        select
        from unnest(procedure) elem
        where elem like '% :String %'
              )
    '''

result=connection.execute(text(my_query),String=String)
```

However it returns nothing,I think maybe "like %" is special ?

Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution is to put the percent signs in the variable itself, and have only `:String` in the query:

```
String = '%hello world%'
my_query = '''
    ...
    where elem like :String
'''
```